# What is the datatype for a column as a number in excel

Tags: excel

When run the value of ColDay1 is 0.  Should the datatype for ColDay1 be different?

```
Dim ColDayName As Variant
Dim ColDay1 As Integer
ColDayName = Array(12, 19, 24)
```

Comment: it is `0` till you assign a value.  `Dim` does not assign a value, it declares the variable.

Comment: and Integer will work fine for column but `Long` is the preferred method of many here.

Comment: ^ Not only preferred, but better, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long).